# Use template literals for multiple classes

Tags: html, components, web-component, template-literals

```
const dummydata = [
  { id: 1, description: "Walk the dog", completed: false },
  { id: 2, description: "Play football", completed: true }
];
```

This is my data I use to create classes in HTML like this:

```
this.root.innerHTML = `
<div ${data.completed ? "class=todo-item done" : "class=todo-item"}> # Does not work
<input type="checkbox" ${data.completed ? "checked" : ""} />
<h4>${data.description}</h4>
</div>`;
```

In my HTML it looks this this:

```
<div class="todo-item" done>
```

"done" is not included in the class. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `${data.completed ? "class=todo-item " + "done" : "class=todo-item"}`

Comment: did you try that? It results in the same result as my code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
this.root.innerHTML = `
    <div class="${data.completed ? 'todo-item done' : 'todo-item'}">
    <input type="checkbox" ${data.completed ? "checked" : ""} />
    <h4>${data.description}</h4>
    </div>
`;
```

Comment: @DataMastery Only the value of the attribute can be changed..

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with missing quotes

```html
<div class=todo-item />
```

will be parsed by the browser to:

```html
<div class="todo-item" />
```

and

```html
<div class=todo-item done />
```

will be parsed by the browser to:

```html
<div class="todo-item" done />
```

So leaving off the quotes is valid, **unless** you have a space

A shorter notation is:

```html
this.root.innerHTML = `
    <div class="todo-item ${data.completed ? 'done' : ''}">
    <input type=checkbox ${data.completed ? 'checked' : ''}/>
    <h4>${data.description}</h4>
    </div>`;
```

Also note the `type=checkbox` without quotes notation, the Browser will add quotes